# Mask overflow text overflow of a rounded image

Tags: css, html, user-interface, user-experience

I'm trying to mask any overflow of text links on top of a rounded image. I have a working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/C4qg5Co0vsuV6S1g?preview)

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="profile-picture" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/male-user-profile-picture_318-37825.jpg">
    <a class="profile-picture-link">Mask the overflow of this text</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.profile-picture{
    height: 250px;
    width:250px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:auto;    
}

.container{
    background:pink;
    margin: auto;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
}

.profile-picture-link{
    background: rgba(255,255,255, .6);
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
}
```

How can I mask the text that overflows the rounded borders of the image?

Comment: so you want to mask the pink part ?

Comment: I want the pink part to show.  I want to mask the Text that overflows the borders of the image

Comment: `position:relative;z-index:999` on image ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif that hides the image behind the border.  The issue is that the Text overlays the image,  But the image is should be the only area where the text should render.   I guess I need another element that inverts the image and uses it as a mask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/):

```css
.profile-picture {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  background: pink;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(43% at 44% 46%);
clip-path: circle(43% at 44% 46%);
}

.profile-picture-link {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="profile-picture" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/male-user-profile-picture_318-37825.jpg">
  <a class="profile-picture-link">Mask the overflow of this text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect,  I'd still like the pink background, but I think I can fix that by putting the mask on another div in the container.  How did you determine the values for the circle though?

Comment: @johnny5 you can use the link I shared to create the paths ;) or simply read about how it works, this on is easy as you defing where to put the center of the circle and the border-radius `(radius at X Y)` so simply adjust the values until you have what you want